# How to use a Bloom Filter across multiple servers?

Tags: java, web-crawler, bloom-filter

I have 50 EC2 instances all crawling the web. Right now they are using Redis on the backend to track URLs that have already been crawled; however, ElastiCache is becoming cost prohibitive, and I keep running into the issue of having too many connections open. I've been looking at implementing a Bloom Filter as a backend, but I don't understand how I can do this so that all 50 servers share the same bloom filter. I don't want each one having their own independent bloom filter, otherwise they're all basically doing the same tasks.

Comment: I would start simple with a stable hashing algorithm such as a hash of the hostname.

Comment: I understand how to implement a bloom filter on each instance. What I don't understand is how to share a single bloom filter across all 50 instances, ensuring instant A is not doing the same work as instance B.

Comment: You partition the work.  That way only one machine will do the work for that machine. e.g. `if (hostname.hashCode() & MASK % machines = thisId) /* do work */`

Comment: you want to implement a distributed BloomFilter? it is not as easy thing to do. You better use an existing database

Comment: @DanielAmaya making a distributed Bloom filter is most likely more difficult than figuring out another way to deal with the same problem.

Comment: The consensus here seems to be that bloom filters are more difficult than they're likely worth. I did find that AWS does not have a timeout on Redis clients, and that JedisPool was seeming to leave a ton of idle connections open. So, it's likely that I'm trying to fix an issue in my code by "ADD MORE MEMORY!" logic. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I guess that the current design that you have is good enough. But just use Bloom filters that are provided by Redis itself.
50 EC2 instance should have 50 or N constant connection with Redis Server and it should be good enough.

Comment: Why not have one instance split the work between all servers? This instance will have a Bloom Filter and it will create crawling requests only for desired URLs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can still use Redis to keep track of the url's that were already processed/crawled in a centralised way, but reduce the memory footprint by using the bloom filter of RedisBloom ([redisbloom.io](https://redisbloom.io)).  RedisBloom is a [Redis Module](https://redis.io/topics/modules-intro) which extends Redis with several probabilistic data structures.

Notes:

- If a single bloom filter would become too large or the throughput becomes too high for a single shard, you can consider having several bloom filters for this case that can be spread across a Redis Cluster and calculate the appropriate filter (key) at client side.
- you might want to bump [this issue](https://github.com/RedisBloom/RedisBloom/issues/94) which requests for items in the bloom filter to expire over time, allowing you to revisit url's after a given time.